# Classification of very noisy EMG signals

Tags: noise, classification, noise-cancellation, deep-learning, emg

I'm an absolutely newbie to signal processing. I'm trying to classify EMG signals which are very noisy (decibel values are more than -70 dB in some cases). After applying EMD  technique these values are improved to -30 dB to -40 dB.

My question is :

I want to classify these EMG signals. It's a binary classification problem. If these noisy signals are fed to a complex classification algorithm like CNN, it will learn the features from the noisy signals only. This knowledge it will apply to classify unknown noisy signals. **As all the samples in my dataset are affected by the same kinds of noises, do the noises affect too much the final validation accuracy ? Or, should I focus in denoising further?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-30 dB is still very noisy.

If you've had success with EMD, I'd try an inspired transform that's improved on it: [synchrosqueezing](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy). Whether it's best to denoise before classifying depends on amount of available data: most denoising will throw away some valuable information, but also make the task easier for a classifier. If there's *lots* of data, don't denoise.

I'd also try scattering which'll yield timeshift-invariant features ([lecture](https://youtu.be/4eyUReyIPXg)); with this much noise one can't hope for precise temporal localization anyway.

Finally I'd look for architectures pretrained on a similar noise profile (or sufficiently powerful to generalize) and attempt transfer learning. But the most promising approach would be data-oriented: find less noisy samples.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll check them  I'm thinking to test these samples on some ML & DL models. After seeing the results, will decide on further denoising.